# Enclose all characters,strings,timestamp and numbers in double quotes using re

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a dictionary which does not have quotes on them. objective is to enclose them on quotes

code that works (python)

```
newstring = """{field1:{abc:1, "def":2,geh:{dt:2019-07-23T23:00:01.000Z,  lp:229.99, op = [dsa,fds,1]}}}"""
textdata = "([\w.]+)"
replacer = re.compile(textdata)
data2 = replacer.sub(r'"\1"', newstring)
```

above code encloses all strings into quotes.
however the timestamp is broken into multiple part
the timestamp is expected to be in ISO8601 format.

i fount epxression which matches the format

```
"""[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(\.[0-9]+)?([zZ]|([\+-])([01]\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)?)?"""
```

but i am having issue making them both work together. could someone help on how to combine two expressions.

expected result is

```
{"field1":{"abc":"1", "def":"2","geh":{"dt":"2019-07-23T23:00:01.000Z",  "lp":"229.99", "op" = ["dsa","fds","1"]}}}
```

Comment: You should fix the JSON at its source.  Regex is not very suitable to this task.

Comment: The source is a external API in this case. so its not possible for me to tweak it. and i am able to consume this without converting it to proper json. if not RE any other approach is also appreciated

Comment: the date field was of no importance to me so replaced it with a dummy string using re.sub. and then performed the first operation to enclose strings within quotes